# Real and imaginary parts of $re^{(2\pi i)^t}$, for $r, t \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: complex-numbers

Is the algebra justified to simply take $re^{(2\pi i)^t}=r\left(\cos ^t(2\pi)+i\sin^t(2\pi)\right)$, thus the real and imaginary parts immediately follow?

Comment: If that were so then e.g. $Re[\cos((2\pi i)^t]=[\cos(2\pi)]^t.$

Comment: Unfortunately, it’s not that simple. Do you know anything about $t$? Regardless, you have to contend with some version of $i^t$. This is a real number for even integers (in particular, $re^{(2\pi i)^t}$ is a real number for even integers $t$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll assume $t$ is real. No, you cannot do that. Choosing the Principal Branch $\operatorname{arg} z\in[-\pi, \pi)$, recall that $i^t=e^{it\pi/2}=\cos(t\pi/2)+i\sin(t\pi/2)$. Hence, we have that
$$
\begin{aligned}
\exp \left(2\pi i\right)^t &=\exp\left[(2\pi)^t\cos(t\pi/2)\right]\exp\left[i(2\pi)^t\sin(t\pi/2)\right] \\
&=\exp\left[(2\pi)^t\cos(t\pi/2)\right]\left[\cos\left((2\pi)^t\sin(t\pi/2)\right)+i\sin\left((2\pi)^t\sin(t\pi/2)\right)\right].
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: So assuming r is real-valued, this means the real and imaginary parts are equivalent?

Comment: Sorry, there was a missing $i$. As you can see now, the real and imaginary parts are distinct.